# Defer evaluation of function but not of its derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, symbolic

Sometimes, the derivative of a function can be simplified nicely using the definition of the function itself. For example, if $f(x) = e^{x^2}$, then 
$$f'(x) = 2x \cdot f(x).$$
How can I perform this simplification in Mathematica?

For example, the input

```
f[x_] := Exp[x^2]
g[x_] := Defer[f][x] + x
g'[x]
```

results in the ouput:

```
1 + f'[x]
```

Instead, I'd like it to output the following:

```
1 + 2x f[x]
```

How can I use `Defer` (or a similar command) such that the evaluation of `f[x]` is deferred, but `f'[x]` is evaluated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you? I only tested it on your example

```
ClearAll[f, x];
f[x_] := Exp[x^2]
(f'[x] /. f[x] -> HoldForm[f[x]]) // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This will work with different variable name

```
 (f'[y] /. f[y] -> HoldForm[f[y]])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 (1 + D[f[x], x]) /. f[x] -> HoldForm[f[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To do `f'[x]^2`, make sure to do the derivative first then square the result, like this

```
 (D[f[x], x] /. f[x] -> HoldForm[f[x]])^2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `Defer` in place of `HoldForm` above. I do not see how this would work if you `Defer` the original `f[x]` at the source, since Mathematica will not be able to take its derivative in first place. So the idea is to do the derivative, then replace the downvalue of `f[x]` by its name back in the result.

If this does not work for you, will delete this answer.

Comment: The problem with this is that, of course, it only finds *literal* occurrences of the value of f[x], so for instance it fails with `(f'[x])^2`.

Comment: Thanks! `HoldForm` was exactly what I was looking for. One issue was that it only works using the same variable name as the function definition, since otherwise `DownValues` doesn't recognize the occurence. E.g. it doesn't work with `D[f[y], y]`.

I'm now using the rule `f[x] -> HoldForm[f[x]]` and it's working great.

Comment: @Nasser btw I upvoted your anwer, but it doesn't show until I gather more karma :)

Comment: @Nasser Following up on my comment above: is there a reason you chose to use `DownValues[f][[1,2]]` rather than simply `f[x]`?

Comment: @atlas no reason. I was trying to be cool. I will change it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would just give `f` an [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) definition for [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative):

```
f /: Derivative[1][f] = Function[x, 2 x f[x]];
```

Then:

```
D[f[x] + x, x]
```

> 1 + 2 x f[x]

Higher order derivatives work as well:

```
D[f[x], {x, 3}]
f'''[x]
```

> 12 x f[x] + 8 x^3 f[x]

> 12 x f[x] + 8 x^3 f[x]

You could also give `f` a numeric definition as well:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Exp[x^2]
```

Then:

```
f'''[1]
```

> 20 E